# How do I upgrade the agent for my bootstrapped environment.

Tags: juju

Right now my local juju is 1.24.2, however each agent that gets created with a new environment always does 1.23

I ran juju-upgrade, however that says no upgrades available.

So how do I properly upgrade the agents on all of the bootstrapped environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New machines that are added to an existing environment use the same version as the initial machine created. This version is shown in `juju status`. The client version doesn't impact the version of the new machines.

Sometimes the upgrade logic seems a little strange. I work on the project and I'm not sure I fully understand it.

In order to upgrade the servers you want to do this:

```
juju upgrade-juju --version=1.24.4
```

The 1.23 releases were known to have some horrible bugs, most of which we hope to have addressed now.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your `agent-stream` option to `proposed`. Something like this:

```
mycloud:
  ...
  agent-stream: "proposed"
  default-series: trusty
```

Valid values for that configuration key are `devel`, `release` and `proposed`.

If you have already bootstrapped, you can change it via `set-env`:

```
juju set-env agent-stream=proposed
```

Comment: This is still something that's under-documented; is https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/streams/v1/index2.sjson the correct place to look for the other possible values of agent-stream (i.e. "devel" and "released")?